# Is it possible to co_await in a catch clause?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

The following code:

```
try {
  throw 42;
} catch (int i) {
  co_await somefuture;
}
```

compiles with clang 6 and 7 with -fcoroutines-ts. However, it does not compile with Visual C++ 15 (2017) Visual C++ 16 (2019) with /await with the error

> C2304: 'co_await' cannot be used inside of a catch block

The C++20 standard draft and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) do not seem to mention anything about it.

Is it a missing feature in the Microsoft compiler or did I misunderstand the standard?

Comment: you shall try VS 2019

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The version of coroutines in 2017 is inspiration for some of what is in the draft standard, it preceeds it.

Comment: Just tested with VS 2019 Preview 1, the error is the same. I can try to provide an MVCE, but since C++ coroutines do not work out of the box, it would depend on something like cppcoro.

Comment: @Philippe it'd make it easier for people with the appropriate toolchain to help you and change nothing for others :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [[expr.await]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#2.sentence-1), emphasis mine:

> An [*await-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#nt:await-expression) shall appear only in a potentially-evaluated expression within the *compound-statement* of a *function-body* **outside of a [*handler*](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#nt:handler) ([except])**.

MSVC is correct to reject.

Comment: Hmm, does that mean we can't write lambdas containing `co_await`?

Comment: I think lambdas containing co_await are fine, even if you create the lambda in a catch clause. However, while you can call the lambda there, you can't co_await its result.